# Silverlight Toolkit Chart Removing Gridlines

Tags: xaml, silverlight, charts, toolkit

I have inherited the work on a StackedColumnSeries Chart and which I turned into a StackedBarSeries, so the graph is on its side, I have two problems:

1. The minimum value does not start at zero.
2. I cannot hide the vertical gridlines.

Please can anybody help me.

The xaml code is below:

```
<Style x:Key="XAxisLabel" TargetType="charting:AxisLabel">
    <Setter Property="StringFormat" Value="{}{0:#,k}"></Setter>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="charting:AxisLabel">
                <TextBlock Text="{TemplateBinding FormattedContent}" />
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>

<Style x:Key="YAxisLabel" TargetType="charting:AxisLabel">
    <Setter Property="StringFormat" Value=""></Setter>
    <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed"></Setter>
</Style>

<Style x:Key="SummaryGraphStyle" TargetType="charting:Chart">
    <Setter Property="PlotAreaStyle">
        <Setter.Value>
            <Style TargetType="Grid">
                <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Left"/>
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
            </Style>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>

    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="charting:Chart">
                <Border BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="1" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}">
                    <Grid>
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <!--<datavis:Title Content="{TemplateBinding Title}" Style="{TemplateBinding TitleStyle}"/>-->
                        <Grid Margin="0,0,0,15" Grid.Row="1">
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                            <Charting_Primitives:EdgePanel x:Name="ChartArea">
                                <Grid ShowGridLines="False" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Canvas.ZIndex="-1"/>

                                <Border BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1,0,0,0" Canvas.ZIndex="10"/>

                            </Charting_Primitives:EdgePanel>
                        </Grid>

                    </Grid>
                </Border>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>


<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="Transparent">
    <Grid ShowGridLines="False" HorizontalAlignment="Center" x:Name="SummaryGraphGrid">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <charting:Chart Loaded="Loaded" Width="{Binding ElementName=Graph, Path=GraphWidth}" Grid.Column="0" BorderBrush="Transparent"  x:Name="SummaryGraph"
                                        Style="{StaticResource SummaryGraphStyle}" BorderThickness="0" 
                                        VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Center">

            <charting:Chart.Axes>
                <charting:LinearAxis AxisLabelStyle="{StaticResource YAxisLabel}" Minimum="0" Location="Right" ShowGridLines="False" BorderThickness="0" Orientation="Y" Background="Transparent"/>
                <charting:CategoryAxis AxisLabelStyle="{StaticResource XAxisLabel}" Margin="5,0,0,0" Location="Left" ShowGridLines="False" BorderThickness="0" Background="Transparent" Orientation="X" />
            </charting:Chart.Axes>
        </charting:Chart>
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

[image: Image of barchart with lines etc]

Comment: For all the work you've been doing in the Chart controls lately, have you been using Blend to dig your way through the control style templates? Sometimes you have to dig a bit.

Comment: Hi Chris, yes I have been using blend and getting the styles and then adding them to the xaml files, I am getting the hang of it, but its a bit different then the normal web development I do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to find a piece of code that will fix this, the code was added the code behind.

```
((StackedBarSeries)this.SummaryGraph.Series[0]).DependentAxis = new LinearAxis() { Minimum = 0, Orientation = AxisOrientation.X };
```

[image]